# Xcode 5 I Can't Validate or Resign an IPA from Another Developer

Tags: iphone, deployment, xcode5

In Xcode 4 we would distribute our application by sending an unsigned IPA to our partners who would resign the IPA with their credentials and post the app to the App Store.

In trying to validate this process in Xcode 5 I am undoable to import an IPA from a different developer into my list of Archives which also means I can't validate it or sign it.  Work arounds I've found on SO involve resigning an IPA but I can't seem to get ahold of the IPA in Xcode to do anything with.

What is the Xcode 5 process for having a 3rd party distribute your application without having access to the source code?